# How to extract substrings from strings in Oracle with PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, substring

I am new to SQL so this question is probably fairly basic, yet I've spent quite a bit of time on it without success.

I was given a block of SQL code that I need to modify. This block currently extracts all tokens ("words") from a text index. What I need to do is to loop over each token and (1) extract all char N-grams of a given length `N` from it and then (2) insert them into a table.

So if a token is `abcdf` and `N=3` then I need to extract `abc`, `bcd`, and `cdf`

I am struggling with (1).

I am doing it in Oracle's PL/SQL: Release 11.2.0.3.0

What I have now is this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE extract_ngrams
AS
     tokens ctx_doc.token_tab;
     w VARCHAR2(255);
     NgramLen NUMBER;
     ngr VARCHAR(10);
BEGIN

-- extract all tokens ("words")
CTX_DOC.TOKENS(myindex,textkey,tokens);

NgramLen := 3;

FOR i IN tokens.FIRST..tokens.LAST LOOP
  w := tokens(i).token;
  dbms_output.put_line(w);
  -- Use SUBSTRING + LEN or some other approach to extract Ngrams of length=NgramLen
  -- insert each Ngram into a table
end loop;

END;
/
```

What is the right way to combine `FOR` loop with `SUBSTRING`, `LEN` and/or whatever other appropriate functions to extract ngrams into `ngr` in a loop in a way similar to how tokens are extracted into `w`?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example of what you want :

```
FOR idx IN 1..(LENGTH(w)-NgramLen+1)
  LOOP
    -- do what you want here
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBSTR(w,idx,NgramLen));
  END LOOP;
```

and don't forget to declare `idx NUMBER;`